# Mongoose: How to validate length of array based on another documents variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do validation within the schema to validate the length of an array based on another documents length of its array. Suppose:

```
const Level = mongoose.Schema({
  level: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    items: {
      exercise: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Exercise",
        required: true,
      },
      accuracyThreshold: { type: Number, required: true },
      timeThreshold: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
  },
});

const UserLevelProgress = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  level: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Level",
    required: true,
  },
  progress: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: (progress) => {
        return progress.length === level.level.length; // level.level.length is not valid
      },
      message: () => "level progress legnth is invalid!",
    },
    items: {
      accuracyScore: { type: Number, required: true },
      timeScore: { type: Number, required: true },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("UserLevelProgress", UserLevelProgress);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Level", Level);
```

I have a validator function in UserLevelProgress, but obviously level is not valid object. How do I get access to this object?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You could implement this validation logic, but is it really a good idea to do this?

**Downsights**

- validation is taking place in the `pre('save')` hook. This means that once you initially save of update a document, the validation will run.
- since `Level` documents are stored in a different collection, the values (including length of the array) can change without `UserLevelProgress` documents noticing. This way your validator would not rerun (as said before it's run in `pre('save')` hook and your documents would technically be not valid anymore.

**Better approach**

- Check if `Level` schema can be included as a nested document, instead of a referenced one. This way validation would be much easier and data will not be able to become invalid unnoticed.

**Implementation if you still want to follow your intended approach**

```
validate: {
      validator: async function(progress) {
        const level = await Level.findById(this.level);
        return progress.length === level.level.length; // level.level.length is not valid
      },
      message: () => "level progress legnth is invalid!",
    },
```

Comment: I really like the detail of your answer, and maybe you can help me with this. The problem with using nested documents, is that many UserLevelProgress documents can contain the same Level document, and an admin of the application is one that sets Level documents, whereas a user makes frequent requests to update their UserLevelProgress documents. I do see what you're saying with Level documents changing without there being any affect on UserLevelProgress documents, but im not sure how to solve that

Comment: I think in this case it‘s possible that your database design is a little bit off. Can you maybe explain a little bit what the `level` and `progress` properties should represent exactly (e.g. with an example in which use case they are set/adjusted)?